# easy graphic for C++

Tags: c++, graphics

What is the easiest framework/IDE fulfilling all following criteria?
If such thing does not exist, what is the nearest?

- compiles C++
- installs in full without problems
- runs under Windows or Linux (1 of those is enough)
- allows to write text to terminal and simultaneously draw graphics
- Hello World is short, about 10 lines for code drawing the simplest graphic dot
- has integrated makefile system or something equivalent
- has editor for multiple files and with code completion (like MSVS)
- help or tutorials are adequate to the installed version

Answer (score 6):

This would be QT, wouldn't it? You've got an IDE (http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/topics-app-development.html) here and the GUI "Hello World" looks like this:

http://qt-project.org/wiki/Qt_for_beginners_Hello_World

```
 #include <QApplication>
 #include <QPushButton>

 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
 {
     QApplication app(argc, argv);

     QPushButton hello("Hello world!");
     hello.resize(100, 30);

     hello.show();
     return app.exec();
 }
```

You can also write text/command line tools from the IDE with or without using the framework.

Answer (score 4):

[Qt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt) framework + [Qt Creator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_Creator) IDE.

Answer (score 1):

[Qt](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6.2/index.html) is not the nearest but it is the destination for you. :)

Answers for your questions in the numeric order:

1. **Qt is a Framework on top of C++** so it does compile C++
2. Install using [this](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6.2/installation.html)...
3. Can be used under both platforms and much more is possible.
4. For normal operation use **[Qt Core module](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qtcore.html)**  and for graphics you can use **[Qt OpenGL module](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6.2/qtopengl.html)**
5. Already answered by *Luther Blissett*
6. **[QMake](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qmake-variable-reference.html)** is available for that purpose
7. **[Qt Creator](http://qt.nokia.com/products/appdev/developer-tools/developer-tools#qt-tools-at-a)** is available as an IDE which has intellisense as well and also can be integrated with Visual Studio also using **[VS Addin](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/vs-add-in-1.0/index.html)**.
8. Isn't it obvious with amount of links I provided. :) Just get start with [this](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6.2/how-to-learn-qt.html)..

Moreover it's **LGPL**.. So give it a try for **free**..

Hope it helps..

Answer (score 1):

If you are really looking for the simplest one, take a look at fltk:

http://www.fltk.org/

1. It's written in C++
2. It works in a variety of platforms
3. GPL
4. It's very fast
5. It does not need of an special make.
6. It also provides FLUID, an UI generator.

As I said, it would be worth taking a look.
If you want a more professional solution, Qt will probably be the best solution, along with Gtk--

http://www.gtkmm.org/